# AccessViolationException when using managed code callback from Fortran Dll

Tags: c#, fortran, dllimport, access-violation

I'm trying to implement some progress notification during time-consuming calculation in my Fortran dll. The problem is that AccessViolationException is raised after some time of execution that depends on optimization options of my compiler (gfortran [-O2|-O3]) Version of compiler - 4.5.0.

Here is my fortran code:

```
subroutine arr2par(sarr, w, l, s, progrs )
  implicit none      
  integer w,l, tmp
  real*8 sarr(w,l)
  real*8 s
  integer i,j, k1, k2       

  interface
    integer function progrs(x,y)
      integer x,y
    end function progrs 
  end interface  

  s = 0
  do j=1,l
    do i=1,w 
        s = s + sarr(i,j) 
        k1 = j+i
        k2 = w*l
        tmp = progrs(k1, k2)
    enddo
  enddo        
end
```

Here is how it is invoked from C#.NET:

```
...
try
{
    var count = 200; 
    var count1 = 400;
    ProgressReporter reporter = Reporter;
    var arr2 = new double[count,count1];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < count1; j++)
        {
            arr2[i,j] = 1;
        }
    }
    double s;
    arr2par_(arr2, ref count, ref count1, out s, reporter);

    InsertMessage("Done: "+s);
    GC.KeepAlive(arr2);
    GC.KeepAlive(reporter);

}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    InsertMessage(exc.Message);
}
...

private int Reporter(ref int value, ref int maxValue)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(value + "-->" + maxValue);
    return 0;
}
private delegate int ProgressReporter(ref int value, ref  int maxValue);

[DllImport("test_dll.for.dll")]
private static extern void arr2par_(
    Double[,] sarr,
    ref Int32 w,
    ref Int32 l,
    out Double r,
    ProgressReporter reporter);
```

Here is typical output:

```
2-->80000
3-->80000
4-->80000
5-->80000
6-->80000
7-->80000
89839819-->80000
89839808-->89839812
1785467715-->7935496
89840016-->1895839696
89839840-->11
49145864-->89840092
1785467715-->89839840
0-->0
A first chance exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in             TestWpfApplication1.exe
```

What's going on with addresses? Is there any better technique?

Comment: just some pointers: (i) does it work without callback, by writing the output inside the subroutine; (ii) can you print the values of the variables w,l inside the subroutine